# Value in CSV file limited to 9 decimal places

Tags: windows-10, csv

I am facing an issue which I believe is being caused by an OS or regional setting, but not sure since I can't seem to fix the issue.
I have two identical .csv files both created on different computers.  When I run code or open them in Excel, one of the csv files limits the amount of decimal places which is displayed to only 9 places.

I have created the following simple csv file which has at least one entry:

```
title,value
"My Name",2.121234521158785
```

This file was created separately on two different Windows PCs (PC A being a physical desktop, PC B being a VDI (Virtual Machine) - not sure if that is relevant).  I then run the following python code which reads the file and outputs the value:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('path_to_file', sep=',')
first_value = df1.loc[0, 'value']
print("Value: ", first_value)
```

The printed result is different for both files, even though the files are completely identical when opened in Notepad.

Result on file A:

```
Value: 2.121234521158785
```

Result on file B:

```
Value: 2.121234521
```

Is there any known setting which I should be aware of when creating csv files?  Perhaps a property on the file is incorrect?

Additionally, on one device when I open the file in Excel, I get the prompt "Excel will perform the following data conversions in this file: Convert large numbers into scientific notation".  If I accept the conversion, the value is limited to 9 decimal places.  If I choose "Don't convert" then the cell is prepended with a ' and the full value is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

A CSV (**C**omma **S**eperated **V**alues, though tab or other characters may be used as separators, too) file is simply *text*, created by an *application*. You can manually create it in a text editor, and there are *no* limitations as to precision. If you [compare the two CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877238/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-diff-command) and they are identical, then the only explanation for getting different results is in the **tools** used to store and **compare** the fields.

Do the machines have the same version of Python? Check that [Python precision](https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/handle-precision-values) is the same on the two PC's. Are the machines using [*floating point* or *decimal*](https://blog.gitnux.com/code/python-float-precision/) arithmetic? Does one or both use [SetPrecision](https://pypi.org/project/SetPrecision/)? Are the operating systems the same?

Are you using MS Excel where the [rounding precision](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-rounding-precision-e5d707e3-07a8-4df2-810c-218c531eb06a) has been set differently? Are the [number of decimal places](https://www.lifewire.com/excel-decimal-format-options-3124037) specified differently?